# Error importing and exporting excel data to vb.net, "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application is not defined"

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am trying to run a file I downloaded to import and export data from excel. 
I downloaded from from the following site:

http://www.sattsoft.com/sourcecodes/details/1/9/import-export-data-to-excel-using-vb-net.html

**When I run the file the error comes on the following lines**

```
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
```

**These are the errors that come on those respective lines**

Type "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application is not defined"

Type "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook is not defined"

Type "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet is not defined"

What I want to do is to run the file without the errors so that I can import and export data from excel to vb.net datagridview.
I am using Excel 2010 and visual studio 2010

How do I get around this error so I can run the file?

Comment: Did you download the example source code? Presumably that compiles without error?

Comment: See the first link [HERE](http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/)

Comment: Yes I am running that. I think the file will be fine as CodeProject.com recommended it.

Comment: @ Siddharth Thanks that is a great link

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add COM reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel  to your project, it's called Microsoft Excel XX.Y Object Library (XX.Y is version number depending of installed Excel).

Comment: Is it under COM components?

Comment: Yes, it's called Microsoft Excel XX.Y Object Library (XX.Y is version number depending of installed Excel)

Comment: There is a
Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
is that the one?

Comment: yes, that's it! btw. if you don't need to handle XLS files but only XLSX/XLSM then you you might take a look at http://closedxml.codeplex.com/ will make handling those files much less painful ;)

Comment: `There is a Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library is that the one? –` @AhmedFaizan: Why ask such questions :)? If you would have taken the time to go through the link that I gave under your question, you would have got the answer. There is a reason why I wrote that blog with step by step instructions...

Comment: + 1 However, I feel you should slightly clarify your answer to avoid such questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this library in references from the "Extensions" section (not not under COM); had to select Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, version 15.0.0.0. 
That fixed the error. 
Selecting the COM reference did not resolve this message.